# Java jackson deserialize json - Getting symbol "=" instead of ":"

Tags: java-8, jackson

This is what I have. I'm trying to deserialize a json but it doesn't work:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Object attribute;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyClass(Object attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    @JsonProperty("attr")
    public Object getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }
}
public void method() {
  InputStream eventsStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("fileName.json");

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.readValue(eventsStream, MyClass.class);
}



fileName.json
{
  "value1": 1,
  "value2": [
    {
      "subValue1": "valueExample"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting this result with symbol "=" instead of ":":

```
{value1=1, value2=[{subValue=valueExample}]}
```

It must be a property or something like that. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the deserialization into a variable?

```
MyClass myClassObject = objectMapper.readValue(eventsStream, MyClass.class);
```

if you do this, you will have direct the deserialized object in `myClassObject` and so you can use it easily.
Another method to deserialize would be to do it using Gson like:

```
new Gson().fromJson(eventStream.toString(), MyClass.class); //you need the eventStream as a String type
```

the import is this one:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Can you please tell us why do you need to print the deserialized value?

Comment: Actually, I save into a variable and compare it against what I expect and it doesn't match. I only showed what is printed. I can't use Gson as it's a legacy code and they don't allow me to include that library, it should work with jackson

Comment: then maybe this is because of the toString method, it doesn't look the same as the one serialized. Maybe for getting the same result you should either compare 2 serialized json or 2 deserialized ones. In your case you could serialize your result and see if it is a match or not, another idea would be to rewrite the toString method as you need it, so to replace the '=' with ':'.

Comment: Actually, I also tried with assertEquals and it says expected blablabla":" but was  blablabla"="

Comment: With assertEquals it is normal to get an error

Comment: Hi! So I've looked a bit over your issue and to compare the json from file with your result you can use: objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass)

Comment: Actually I applied objectMapper.readValue( in the expected parameter and it worked. Not the best solution but I took me a lot of time to come up with this work around. Thanks for your help